How to trigger input's blur event when submitting form by pressing enter
I have the following simple HTML form:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      function onBlur() {
        console.log("blur  event");
      }
      function onSubmit(e) {
        console.log("submit  event", e);
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onSubmit="onSubmit(event)">
      <input name="code" onBlur="onBlur()" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>



When submitting the form by pressing the enter key, the input does not lose focus, and the blur event is never called.
Is there a way to disable this behavior? I can query for the input and call the blur function, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it.

"cleaner way" could be to use the input event instead of blur.  Depends on your requirements.

@fdomn-m, thank you!  Unfortunately, I have to use the blur event.


I can query for the input and call the blur function, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it.

Yes, you can call blur() on the document.activeElement:
document.activeElement.blur()




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      function onBlur() {
        console.log("blur  event");
      }
      function onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.activeElement.blur()
        console.log("submit  event");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onSubmit="onSubmit(event)">
      <input name="code" onBlur="onBlur()" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>



